# Setting values inside loop; I want to reset the values if SQL Exception is thrown

Tags: java, loops, exception

I have a table with customer info, and if some of the fields get changed, I am updating the database and my Customer objects. I want to avoid setting the Customer values when the database update fails for one of the rows.
EDIT: The Database is updated correctly, but not my internal Customer model.

```
try{
    MysqlConnection mysql = new MysqlConnection();
    mysql.setAutoCommit(false); //set Autocommit off, so it doesnt commit if one of the rows fails to update
   for(int row = 0; row < model.getRowCount(); row++){
       boolean rowHasChanged = false;
       int id = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString()); // hidden column
       String firstName = table.getValueAt(row,0).toString();
       String lastName = table.getValueAt(row,1).toString();
       Customer c = Customer.getByID(id) // getting the Customer objects by hidden ID column
       //Compare model values with table input
       if(c.getFirstName != firstName){
           rowHasChanged = true;
       }
       if(c.getLastName != lastName){
           rowHasChanged = true;
       }
       if(rowHasChanged){
           c.setFirstName(firstName);
           c.setLastName(lastName);
           mysql.updateCustomer(c.getID(), firstName, lastName);
       }
    }
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

and the object that handles the sql queries

public class MysqlConnection {
    private Connection conn;

```
public MysqlConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","","");
}

public void updateCustomer(int id, String firstName, String lastName){
   String query = "UPDATE customers SET firstName=?, lastName=? WHERE id=?;";
   PreparedStatement statement = this.prepareStatement(query);
   statement.setString(1, firstName);
   statement.setString(2, lastName);
   statement.setInt(3, id);
}

public void setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit) throws SQLException{
    conn.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
}


}
```

Comment: Read about Transactions, commit and rollback

Comment: im setting autocommit=false so the database changes shouldn't be commited if one of the rows failed. but the lines            c.setFirstName(firstName);
           c.setLastName(lastName); will change my java model

Comment: so I want to not set the setter variables in case the SQL call fails.

Comment: if the SQL fail in row 3, some rows get changed and some won't

Comment: Not if you are using one Transaction for all upadtes and make a rollback if you get an SQLException

Comment: but i think transactions only handle the database updats, not setting values in my internal model.